# Move background image while hovering div

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Any suggestions on how to accomplish a div containing a background image which is only visible while hovering. and while hovering i want the image to either zoom-in or move to the sides.
Here is my current progress.

```css
.seg1 p:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 10%;
}

.seg1 p {
  color: #363e3e;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 10%;
}

.seg1 p:nth-child(3) {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 10%;
}

.seg1 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #b1ebeb;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f1fbfb;
}

.seg1:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/350/000000/FFFFFF/?text=BackgroundImage);
}
```

```html
<div class="seg1">
  <p> test </p>
  <p> dont </p>
  <p> bother </p>


</div>
```

thank you in advance.

## The answer might get broken in the future

Embedding a working example here instead.

---

```css
.seg1 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #b1ebeb;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #f1fbfb;
}

.seg1:hover {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: zoomin;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomin;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350/000000/FFFFFF/?text=Background-image');
  background-position: center;
}

@keyframes zoomin {
  from {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
  to {
    background-size: 200%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  from {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
  to {
    background-size: 200%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="seg1">
  <p>Click</p>
  <p>To send me an email</p>
  <p>For business enquiries</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also the option of using CSS animation. Support is roughly the same as CSS transition (http://caniuse.com/css-animation, http://caniuse.com/css-transitions), but the code is a bit longer (mostly because you'll have to add the -webkit prefix versions as well).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/32Qrb/3/

Relevant CSS:

```
.seg1{
-webkit-border-radius:400px;
border:1px solid #b1ebeb;
height:250px;
width:250px;
float:left;
background-color:#f1fbfb;
}

.seg1:hover{
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: zoomin;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomin;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/256/256'); 
    background-position: center;
}

@keyframes zoomin {
  from {
      background-size: 100%;
  }

  to {
      background-size: 200%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  from {
      background-size: 100%;
  }

  to {
      background-size: 200%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/xE4q4/***

1. Its advisable to define your transition in the base class and not on the `:hover` or other *change* pseudo-class.
2. Specify a background on the element in the base class itself.
3. Just specify what change you want in your `:hover` pseudo-class.

*Relevant CSS*:

```
.seg1 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #b1ebeb;
    height: 250px; width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('your image') no-repeat center center #f1fbfb;
    background-size: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.seg1:hover {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try this for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3q9ex/

```
background-position: -100px center;
```

And play with this:

```
background-size: cover;
```